# SSAS Dimension not displaying values in rows in Cube Browser

Tags: sql, ssas, cube, dimensions

I am new to SSAS. Have added a new dimension to cube and when i see under members it shows the value of that columns but under browser section when i drag and drop the dimension it does not display anything
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We need more information on what steps you took to get where you're at.

Do you have a relationship between the dimension and measure group?
Did you process the dimension, the cube?

[image]

Comment: we have excel templates which have connections to the cube and there was a requirement to display certain date ranges and for that I have to make a new Dimtable into my datamart . I have to first make a bridge table in between Dimdate and my table in order to make a relation.I fetched this table into my cube and added a new dim and deployed and processed the cube which brings that dim in the cube. The bridge table contains FK which refers the PK of DimDate table and the PK of Bridge table is being refered by my table and my table has id as a PK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that you haven't included a measure in the cube browser so it returned only the report dates which have a value for the "default measure". If you go to the first tab of the cube designer and right click on the cube node above the measure groups list on the left and choose Properties you will see a DefaultMeasure property. You can set that property to choose the measure which is the "default measure" when a user doesn't specify a measure in their report.

However I would recommend just dragging a measure into the cube browser to explicitly tell it to show report dates that have a value in that measure.

I also prefer not setting the DefaultMeasure property and adding the following to the MDX script so that the default measure is always null. That forces users to explicitly add a measure to their pivot so it is clear what they want.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[NullCalc] as NULL
,VISIBLE=0;

ALTER CUBE CURRENTCUBE UPDATE DIMENSION Measures, DEFAULT_MEMBER=[Measures].[NullCalc];
```